# Measure algebras and measure spaces

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. It is known that two sets $A,B\in\mathcal{A}$ which symmetrically differ by a set of measure $0$ have the same properties
from the point of view of measure theory. Hence, in practice, we study the Boolean $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{I}$ (where $\mathcal{I}$ is the $\sigma$-ideal of sets of measure $0$) with the measure $\bar{\mu}$ defined on $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{I}$ such that $\bar{\mu}([A])=\mu(A)$ for every $A\in\mathcal{A}$. The pair $(\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{I},\bar{\mu})$ is called the measure algebra of $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$.

I have a simple question (which is rather a verification):

By definition, two sets are in the same equivalence class if they symmetrically differ by a set of measure $0$. They may have other properties of interest though. So, suppose that I am interested in the measure of one of them; call it the representative of the equivalence class. Does it make sense to talk about the measure $\bar{\mu}(A)$, where $A$ is the representative of $[A]$ and $\bar{\mu}$ is the measure on $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{I}$, or should I rather talk about the measure $\mu(A)$? (The latter seems more coherent; yet all elements of a given equivalence class having the same measure, I can just pick one of them and assign to it the measure $\bar{\mu}$(?))

Comment: Welcome. It might be advisable to use a more specific title - there are myriad different questions that could be asked involving measure algebras

Comment: It seems as if $\overline{\mu}([A])=\mu(A)$ so there is no problem. You just have to be generally careful that everything you're doing is well-defined up to null symmetric difference. It is common for authors to relax notation for the sake of brevity when they know it's ok, but you should make sure in your own work and in reading the work of others that every operation with ambiguous representative-versus-equivalence class notation is well-defined

Comment: To be very strict, it is not good style, as the domain of $\bar \mu$ is the set of equivalence classes of $\mathcal A$ and you would be extending the domain of $\bar \mu$ to include members of $\mathcal A$.  But in practice people do this, and similar "abuses"  a lot. E.g. when discussing the Hilbert space $L^2[0,1]$ we often do not bother to distinguish between a function $f$ and the equivalence class $[f]\in L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet So is it fair to say that, although abusive, we have $\bar{\mu}(A)=\bar{\mu}([A])=\mu(A)$?

Comment: @FShrike . Yes, A set-theorist would object that in general it is possible for a member $A\in\mathcal A$ could also be an equivalence class $[B]$ with $\mu(A)\ne\mu (B)$. But in analysis it is often assumed (tacitly) that we are using only anti-transitive sets, i.e.  $x\subset S\implies x\not\in S$ to avoid this difficulty.

Comment: @student. Yes, but only if you assume $A\not\in \mathcal A / \mathcal I$. We usually just assume we  are discussing an isomorphic copy in which this difficulty does not arise . Another common use (or abuse) is to write $f(A)$ for $\{f(x): x\in A\}$ when $A\subset dom (f).$ E.g. suppose $A=\emptyset \in dom (f)$.....  I prefer $f[A]$ for $ \{f(x): x\in A\}.$